# Crawler in jsoup (need optimization )

Tags: java, html, jsoup, web-crawler

I made a crawler in Java with the help of jSoup and I need optimizations or suggestions to make my crawler better and error free. And please help me to understand the for each loop in last for(Element link: questions) what this loop actually do does it fetches all the links of the same page and then crawl or just find the first link and crawl to that link.

Thanks in advance

```
  public class crawler_html {
  public static db_Connection db = new db_Connection();
  public crawler_html(String url) throws SQLException, IOException
 {      //db.runSql2("TRUNCATE Record;");
    processPage(url);
 }
public static void processPage(String url) throws SQLException, IOException{
    //check if the given URL is already in database
    String sql = "select * from crawler where URL ='"+url+"'";
    ResultSet rs = db.runSql(sql);
            if(rs.next()){
                System.out.println("URL Found");
                //If url found what to do next

    }else{
              System.out.println("Store the URL to database");
        //store the URL to database to avoid parsing again
        sql = "INSERT INTO crawler (URL) VALUES ('"+url+"')";
        PreparedStatement stmt = db.conn.prepareStatement(sql);

                     if(stmt!=null){
                         stmt.execute();
                         System.out.println("Executed well");

             }
        //get useful information
                     // timeout(0) sets the time to infinite
        Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url)
                            .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/27.0.1453.110 Safari/537.36")
                            .timeout(0)
                            .ignoreHttpErrors(true)
                            .followRedirects(true)
                            .execute()
                            .parse();

        //get all links and recursively call the processPage method
        Elements questions = doc.select("a[href]");
                       for(Element link: questions){
                        {
                                    db.stmtclose();
                processPage(link.attr("abs:href"));
                           }
        }
                    }
        }
    }
}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well firstly , i do not see the need for recursive calling. It will just make your code more complex.

You can have two methods , one method to check if the URL exists in the db and based on that the logic to insert or go ahead.

Another method to fetch data from the page.

So i would write it something like this:

```
public class htmlCrawler{

    public static db_Connection db = new db_Connection();

    public htmlCrawler(String url){

    getLinksFromPage(url);
}

public boolean checkInDb(String url){
//your data base logic here
}

public boolean getLinksFromPage(String url){

//your jsoup thing

//the loop

Elements questions = doc.select("a[href]").getAll();
for(Element link: questions){
                    {
                      String link = link.attr("abs:href");
                      checkInDb(link);
                       }
    }

}
```

Let me know if u need more help.

Comment: Hey thanks Nischal for help, it is very useful and please tell me something I have to add to this crawler to make it more better. And please help me with the exception could occure

Comment: When you are writing something for the first time ,use an IDE for example ECLIPSE , it will help you handle exceptions.
Avoid recursions until and unless you are sure you need it.
If you think my previous answer helped you , please mark it as answer.